# JPQL select query for ElementCollection

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I have the following entity with `enum` collection. I would like to search the user with an `enum` parameter.
The user might have multiple permission. When I search the users with the parameter like `Permission.APPROVE`, there may be one or more user who have that permission.
How can I write `JPQL` query?

User.java

```
@Entity
....
public class User implements Serializable {

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Permission.class)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(name = "USER_PERMISSION", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERMISSION", referencedColumnName = "ID")) 
    private List<Permission> permisssionList;
}
```

Permission.java

```
public enum Permission {
    REGISTER, APPROVE, REJECT, CONFIRM;
}
```

How to write ?

```
public List<User> findUserList(Permission permission) { 
    Query q = em.createQuery(.....);
    result = q.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From spec

> Enum literals support the use of Java enum literal syntax. The
>   fully qualified enum class name must be specified.

```
select u from User u where u.Permission = XX.XX.Permission.APPROVE
```

Try this one.

```
String jpql = 
    "select u from User u join u.permission p"
    + " where p = :enumeration";
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("enumeration", XX.XX.Permission.APPROVE);
```

Answer (score 29):

`@Embeddable` and `@CollectionTable` are just a simple way to map One To Many relationships, they can not be queried directly nor persisted, but certainly can be joined, do it like  you would with any One To Many relationship:

```
"select user from User user join user.permissionList p where p = :permission"
```

and pass the enum as a regular parameter